# Laravel 4.2 does not show error when trying t upload file over php.ini limit

Tags: php, laravel

So when I try to upload files over the size or max number of files per upload Laravel just proceeds as if everything just worked fine without giving me any kind of error, but nothing got uploadad. Is there any way to make it show when it couldn't upload a file for a limit on php.ini?

Code of the controller

```
public function upload($stockId) {

        $stock = Stock::find($stockId);

        if($stock->company_id == Auth::user()->company_id) {

            if(Request::isMethod('get')) {

                return View::make('stocks.upload', [
                    'stock' => $stock,
                ]);

            }
            else {

                if (!file_exists(storage_path().'/stocks/'.$stock->id)) {
                    File::makeDirectory(storage_path().'/stocks/'.$stock->id."/available",0777,true);
                    File::makeDirectory(storage_path().'/stocks/'.$stock->id."/used",0777,true);
                }

                // Count # of uploaded files in array
                $total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

                // check pdf extension
                for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {

                    $bytes = File::size($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i]);

                    if($bytes > 10000000){
                        return Redirect::back()
                            ->withErrors(['El archivo es demasiado grande']);
                    }

                    //Get the temp file path
                    $file = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
                    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if($ext != "pdf") {
                        return Redirect::back()
                            ->withErrors(['El archivo debe ser pdf']);
                    }

                }

                for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
                    //Get the temp file path
                    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                    //Make sure we have a filepath
                    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){                        
                        //Upload the file into the temp dir
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, storage_path().'/stocks/'.$stock->id.'/available/'.$name)) {

                        }
                    }
                }

                return Redirect::to(url('/stocks'))
                    ->with('message', 'Datos guardados correctamente');

            }

        }

        else {

            App::abort(400, 'Access not allowed');

        }

    }
```

Comment: What is your code ? please add

Comment: Added the code.